# Getting started with GraphicsMagick

Tags: c, graphicsmagick

I find the (C) API to be very complicated, there are many functions which sound like that they are doing the same thing. The relationship between blob<->image<->registry<->streams> confuses me.

Has anyone found tutorials or can otherwise shed light on what the fundamental concepts of GraphicsMagick are? A few typical workflows like "if you want to work with an image in memory, you can do [...], then to write it to disk, do [...]"

Simple tasks like this are hard.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have already overcome your problem, but if not- I think that C++ API for GraphicsMagick is quite simple to use in terms that you have specified, see [documentation](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html). So if C++ is acceptable for you, it is quite reasonable option.